# Vim Last Position Mark Only Works with Sudo

Tags: vim

on a new install of Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, I am having trouble with vim jumping to the last position on file reopen.  For some reason the mark `'"` only works when I do `sudo vim file`, otherwise it doesn't.  Because of this, the following in my vimrc file (/etc/vim) isn't doing anything

```
if has("autocmd")
   au BufReadPost * if line("'\"") > 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") | exe "normal! g'\"" | endif
endif
```

But this line works fine with `sudo vi file`?  I've been at this for a few hours now and it's really bothering me.  This works on other machines just fine though (without sudo) such as a Mac I have.

Comment: What does `ls -l ~/.viminfo` say?

Comment: `-rw------- 1 root root 3788 Nov  7 22:09 /home/username/.viminfo`, and in it I have `set autoindent` which works fine

Comment: OK, you need to delete that file, then run `vim` (without `sudo`).

Comment: Perfect, that worked, thank you so much!

Comment: Unrelated suggestion, you should consider using "sudo -e" (or "sudoedit") rather than "sudo vim".  This lets vim run as your user and only elevates privileges to read/write the file.  Note that this will launch whatever "$EDITOR" is set to, so if you want to launch vim you need to set "$EDITOR" to vim.

Comment: Never knew about that, I'll start using that now, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last position in a file is stored in a mark. Marks are saved in `~/.viminfo`. If you have a `.viminfo` in your home directory that is owned by a different user, vim can't write to it.

In your case you had a `~/.viminfo` owned by root. Running `sudo vim` worked because vim was running as root, but your normal user didn't have permissions to update the file.

By deleting the root-owned `~/.viminfo` you clear the way for vim to re-create the file on the next run, this time as your normal user.

Comment: No idea how that happened, but it works now, so thank you!